# Nginx Server on Raspbian results in Error

Tags: node.js, nginx, phpmyadmin, debian, raspbian

So I managed to setup Nginx and phpmyadmin/php and mysql successfully on my server, which is hosted by my raspberry pi 4. I sought to have Node.js as my backend, and did everything according to the various tutorials there is online. The moment I created the reverse-proxy, I wasnt able to access phpmyadmin,
and then I started playing around with the configuration and the error started to appear.

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

# SSL configuration
#
# listen 443 ssl default_server;
# listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
#
# Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
#
# Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
# See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
#
# Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
# Don't use them in a production server!
#
# include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

root /var/www/html;

# Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

server_name codenoury.se www.codenoury.se;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

# pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    # include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    # fastcgi_index index.php
    # fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

}

The status code I get is:

```
root@raspberrypi:/etc/nginx/sites-available# root@raspberrypi:/etc/nginx/sites-available# systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-04-12 20:03:42 CEST; 27min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 19140 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 59ms

Apr 12 20:03:42 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Apr 12 20:03:42 raspberrypi nginx[19140]: nginx: [emerg] unexpected "}" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/codenoury.se:73
Apr 12 20:03:42 raspberrypi nginx[19140]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Apr 12 20:03:42 raspberrypi systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 12 20:03:42 raspberrypi systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 12 20:03:42 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

I have created both a user with host = localhost and one with host being the ip-adress to the website. phpmyadmin is located in the right directory (according to sources) on /var/www/html/

The node.js application runs on port 5000 as you can probably see in the configuration file.
I'm using Uncomplicated Firewall (ufw) as firewall, and if I check the status, everything seems to work fine:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

So the question is:

1. How can I make phpmyadmin work, and accessible while using node.js as server and using reverse proxy on port 80, while having node.js work as well.
2. How do I get nginx to work again?

Thanks in advance. Let me know if you require any further information!

Comment: Check /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/codenoury.se line 73 it may have a extra "}"

Comment: @PatrickTannoury also check your nginx configuration syntax with `nginx -t` after you've changed it

Comment: Hi, you can see config file, and that there isn't an extra '}'. I think rather that I have messed something up under the php and phpmyadmin configuration...